# Criar um servidor de background

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

É bem simples, esse código funciona, porém apenas uma vez, depois da primeira vez que ele é iniciado nenhuma outra requisição é atendida, como se depois dele rodar uma vez o StreamSocketListener parasse.

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    var detalhes = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as SocketActivityTriggerDetails;
    if (detalhes.SocketInformation.SocketKind == SocketActivityKind.StreamSocketListener &&
        detalhes.Reason == SocketActivityTriggerReason.ConnectionAccepted)
    {
        var list = detalhes.SocketInformation.StreamSocketListener;
        list.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            using (DataWriter escritor = new DataWriter(args.Socket.OutputStream))
            {
                escritor.WriteString("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nOK");
                await escritor.StoreAsync();
            }
        };
    }
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

O registro da tarefa de background é feito com esse código:

```
private void Registrar()
{
    var tasks = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks;
    int quant = tasks.Values.Count(x => x.Name == "SocketActivityBackgroundTask");
    if (quant == 1)
    {
        task = tasks.Values.Single(x => x.Name == "SocketActivityBackgroundTask");
    }
    else
    {
        var socketTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        socketTaskBuilder.Name = "SocketActivityBackgroundTask";
        socketTaskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = "SocketActivityBackgroundTask.SocketActivityTask";
        var trigger = new SocketActivityTrigger();
        socketTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);
        task = socketTaskBuilder.Register();
    }
}

private async Task Iniciar()
{
    var sockets = SocketActivityInformation.AllSockets;
    if (!sockets.Keys.Contains(socketId))
    {
        StreamSocketListener socket = new StreamSocketListener();
        socket.EnableTransferOwnership(task.TaskId, SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction.DoNotWake);
        await socket.BindServiceNameAsync(serverPort);
        await Task.Delay(500);
        await socket.CancelIOAsync();
        socket.TransferOwnership(socketId);
    }
}
```

O registro funciona e a tarefa vai pra o background, mas ela só funciona uma vez, e esse é o atual problema, porque o anterior foi resolvido mas esse foi criado.

Comment: Será que não quer dizer "Criar um SERVIÇO" ?

Comment: É que eu uso o StreamSocketListener para hospedar uma página Web, então por isso chamo isso de servidor.

Comment: Agora a pergunta está clara o suficiente?

Comment: Coloque o código de como é feita a chamada/registro do servidor/serviço

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Pronto, precisa de mais algum detalhe?

Comment: Agora ficou mais fácil de entender e tentar identificar o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Não é tão simples, segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/guidelines-for-background-tasks) além do uso de `deferrals` quando uma função assíncrona é realizada, também é recomendado:
`(Re-register your background tasks during app launch.)` ´Desregistrar` e registrar novamente uma tarefa durante o inicio da aplicação, dentre outras recomendações.

```
foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
{
   if (cur.Value.Name != name) continue;
   cur.Value.Unregister(true);
}
```

Como o processo necessita ficar em execução, aparentemente o uso do `deferral.Complete();` , faz a tarefa parar de responder as solicitações `SocketActivityTrigger`.

Preparei um exemplo funcional com as implementações mostradas aqui, o código fonte está no final da resposta.

Obviamente o código necessita ser melhorado mas demonstra o funcionamento de uma aplicação simples `UWP cliente/servidor` baseado na comunicação via `sockets`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Código Fonte:
>   https://github.com/rubgithub/ClientServerSocketUWP

> Referencias:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/guidelines-for-background-tasks
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36500.uwp-linux-socket-communication-handling-communciation-in-the-backgroundtask.aspx
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSocket

Comment: Nossa, que resposta completa, amanhã analisarei essa solução que você me mandou, caso tudo dê certo (estou implorando a Deus para que dê certo), criarei uma branch em minha solução para aprimorar seu projeto.

Comment: Infelizmente sua solução não funciona como eu esperava, sequer eu posso me conectar ao servidor.

Comment: Acredito que para o problema proposto na pergunta funcione. Agora se estiver enfrentando outro tipo de problema ou estive tentando algo que não esteja dentro do escopo da pergunta sugiro fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: O problema é que eu não consigo fazer com que o seu projeto funcione, simplesmente não funciona. Eu não consigo fazer o servidor receber uma requisição pelo Edge de jeito nenhum :(

Comment: Acredito que o gatilho `SocketActivityTask` não é disparado em requisições `HTTP`, ao menos nos testes realizados aqui. Recomendo fazer novas pesquisas e, se for o caso, complementar a pergunta ou fazer uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Ele é sim, pra tanto que no projeto da pergunta ele é disparado, mas só uma vez, porque acontece um erro se eu chamar o TransferOwnership.

Comment: Como seria a chamada via browser? Seria `http://localhost:123` por exemplo?

Comment: Eu usaria meu celular, e seria http://192.168.0.102:1337

Comment: Então... Alguma ideia de como ajeitar seu projeto, eu até tentaria ajeitar aqui, mas vou instalar agora o VS 2017.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55781/discussion-between-rubstackoverflow-and-jaedson-barbosa).